# Batch file - Missing operator

Tags: t-sql, batch-file, operators

this is my first post, please go easy if I have done something wrong :-)

Can anyone tell me why I am getting Missing operator on this?

```
@echo off
mode con: cols=100 lines=50
TITLE Availability check

set /a go = 0

echo go start = %go%
pause

:loop
set /a go = sqlcmd -S SERVERNAME -E -W -i "FILEPATH\FILENAME.sql" -h-1  -m 1

echo go SQL = %go%
pause

echo testing go
pause

if %go% == 1 goto next

TIMEOUT /T 300
:next

echo(yay
pause

goto loop
```

the messages (pauses) were just so I could isolate the line where the error occurred...I think it's to do with the sqlcmd.  I'm trying to get a 1 or 0 returned from a SQL table (conditions applied) which would trigger an event on another server/application (not shown in code).  If 0 it should try again in 5 minutes.

Any help would be appreciated as I'm new to using batch files.

Thanks

Comment: `set /A` is for arithmetic operations, so you cannot assign the string `sqlcmd -S SERVERNAME -E -W -i "FILEPATH\FILENAME.sql" -h-1  -m 1` to a variable, unless you remove the `/A` option and make sure that there are no spaces around the `=`-sign...

Comment: Batch files do not work like `BASH`. You cannot assign the output of a command directly to a variable.  If you need to capture the output of a command you have two options. 1) Write the output to a file and use a `FOR /F` command to read the file. 2) You can use the `FOR /F` command to directly read the output of the `SQL` command by putting it within in the `IN` clause of the `FOR` command.

Comment: Thanks, I've now changed it to `sqlcmd -S SERVERNAME -E -W -i "FILEPATH\FILENAME.sql" -h-1  -m 1 -o RPRresult.txt
set /p go=<RPRresult.txt`